# Returns Mysql SQL results in JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am trying to implement [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) to my site.

The typeahead.js will take from a remote page that would return JSON,
something like: `http://example.org/search?q=%QUERY`

For my site, this is what I've wrote for the PHP:

```
$q=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);

$getship= @mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE data1 LIKE \'%'.$q.'%\' OR schar LIKE \'%'.$q.'%\';');

while($tbl=mysql_fetch_array($getship)){
    $id=$tbl['id'];
    $data1=$tbl['data1'];
    $fplod=explode(" ",$data1);
    $data2=$tbl['data2'];
    $splod=explode(" ",$data2);
    $data3=$tbl['data3'];
    $data4=$tbl['data4'];
    echo '{
            "value":'.$id.',
            "tokens":["'.$fplod[0].'","'.$fplod[1].'","'.$splod[0].'","'.$splod[1].'"],
            "data1" :"'.$data1.'",
            "data2":"'.$data2.'",
            "data3":"'.$data3.'",
            "data4":"'.$data4.'"
        }';
}
```

But when ever I ask that typeahead thing to return, it seems to return in text/html and not application/json [image: screenshot from Chrome browser] .

How can I make this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with JSON so I'm not really sure my JSON structure is correct for the TypeAhead to work... But I'll work on that later (as soon as this is solved, which I think the reason this snippet won't run)

Comment: Isn't the answer type set by the client application and then just used by the server for the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Content-Type` header yourself. Before any output is sent, call [`header`](http://php.net/header):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this code because I don't feel like using the json encoder.

Comment: @KoiFish: Er, you should actually use both. What’s wrong with a JSON encoder? It will be a lot safer. And as it is, you have SQL injection problems, too…

Answer (score 2):

That is not valid JSON.  You do not have quotes around the names.  PHP has built in json encoding/decoding functions already so you don't have to build the string yourself.

```
echo json_encode(array("value" => $id /* etc
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to convert your data into json manually, rather use `json_encode`

```
$data = array();
while($tbl=mysql_fetch_array($getship)){
   $data[] = $tbl;
}
$return = array("data"=>$data);
echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getship, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $row_set[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($row_set);
```

you can also use mysql_fetch_assoc.